# Native Query convert to HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have been using native query in jpa for below query since I'm eagerly fetching relations table before but recently I'm having a lot more increment of data in my database, so I'm implementing lazy fetch for some of the relations table. Now I'm having trouble to convert below query to HQL query to solve the LazyInitializeException. Can anyone help?

Native Query :

```
@Query("SELECT * from tableA a inner join (select DISTINCT ON (auid) * from tableB where " +
"status = 4 order by auid,date_created desc ) b on a.uid = b.auid inner join tableC c on " +
"c.uid = b.uid where a.group_uid = :groupUid and c.condition = 1 and c.status = 0 and " +
"b.type <> 2 and b.enable = true", nativeQuery = true) 
List<TableA> findListA(@Param("groupUid") String groupUid)
```

Note : My workaround right now is using the query above to select uid from tableA, then run another query below using HQL to fetch tableB and tableC relation :

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM TableA JOIN FETCH a.tableB JOIN a.tableB.tableC WHERE a.uid = :uid")
TableA getOne(@Param("uid" String uid)
```

Comment: are you using transactions? Please post the stacktrace

Comment: @WeMakeSoftware no im not using transactional annotations. Would having transactions solve my LazyInitializeException?

Comment: There are performance issues in the native query `distinct on (auid) *` and `order by` in the subquery. Why do you need `distinct on`? are you trying to get "the most recent" row (and that's why you are ordering it)?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell yes, im trying to get the most recent row of tableB. tableB got manytoone relation to tableA.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspicious of the `distinct on` and this alternative "might" help:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN a.tableb b
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT auid, MAX(dateCreated) AS maxDateCreated
    FROM TableB
    WHERE status = 4 AND b.type <> 2 AND b.enable = true
    GROUP BY auid
    ) b2 ON b.auid = b2.auid AND b.dateCreated = b2.maxDateCreated
INNER JOIN b.tablec c
WHERE a.groupUid = :groupUid AND c.condition = 1 AND c.status = 0
```

However that b2 subquery "might" not limit subquery to just 1 row per auid although this would only occur if multiple rows can share the maximum date (hopefully really a timestamp).

If that approach isn't useful, then perhaps this will work:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM TableA a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.auid) b 
    FROM TableB b 
    WHERE b.status = 4 AND b.type <> 2 AND b.enable = true
    ORDER BY b.auid, b.dateCreated DESC
    ) b ON a.uid = b.auid 
INNER JOIN TableC c ON c.uid = b.uid 
WHERE a.groupUid = :groupUid AND c.condition = 1 AND c.status = 0
```